# Why does clicking on a TextFormField trigger didUpdateWidget()?

Tags: flutter

I've ran into a problem. In one section of my page I have a date with today's date.  If the user clicks on an arrow to the right it goes forward a date and if they person clicks an arrow to the left it goes back a date.  On the arrow buttons I am using setState.  The date changes perfectly fine.

I also have a form below on a separate card.  To each textFormField I h ave a controller set up. I had to set these up because initialvalue: only gets called once so the fields were never changing with the date.

Anyway the fields now change with the date and it is correct.  But the moment I click on the form, The top widget date shoots back to the initial value it was at?

I checked this by setting up a didUpdateWidget override and this is firing every time I click on the form field??? Why is this happening.  I am not updating anything yet.

When I used a controller for the date value displayed between the two arrows it doesn't change but when I hit submit the value it's supposed to be assigned to is the wrong (very first date that appears).  So it seems like when didUpdate fires it is setting that field which I have set in my extends StatefulWidget class{}.

EDIT: Wow typing that last sentence made me realize I needed to set the value in my bottom class that extends State<>.  I was using it with widget.activeDay.

I guess I'm still curious as to why this is happening with the text form field though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on a text-field opens the keyboard.

This changes the screen dimensions and leads to `MaterialApp` rebuilding the route.

The route rebuilding ultimately calls `didUpdateWidget` on that specific widget.

Comment: Any way to prevent calling `didUpdateWidget`  while typing into TextFormField?